# Change the way users are ordered in the users tab

Tags: feature-request, users, sorting, users-page

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users

They are ordered by rep, but the way it's done feels very unnatural and it took me a while to understand how it worked. Basically you have to read column by column instead of line by line.

Jon Skeet, at 2x1, is second.. Kyle at 1x2 is 8th.

I think it would be much better if they were ordered so that the first line has the top 5 users, and so on.

```
aaettkioa
fld eesrt
tlow  ,te
e nrlt ul
rw'iihfny
```

Comment: We don't write like this, but we are used to lists of items being displayed vertically. Multicolumn tables in newspapers are displayed like that, e.g. the temperatures in different cities.

Comment: Let me guess: You played the old-school *Might and Magic* series of games, didn't you? :) Still don't like the idea, but I applaud the way you made your point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading down the list of users is quieter than wading through the mucky mess of rows.

There is a wider, gentler, sense of calming whitespace between the columns than there is between the rows.

The ample sum of relaxation as you scan down affords a breathing channel as you slide down the board of Snakes and Ladders.

[image: phantom and hulk have easier time between columns]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. We are all used to the existing order now.

Comment: I don't know about you but I don't visit that page so often that the "correct" order would suddenly confuse me.